# Use pylab.scatter and cmap in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

When I use Python2, I can plot graphs

```
from sklearn import datasets
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
circles = datasets.make_circles()

colors = ListedColormap(['red', 'blue'])
pyplot.figure(figsize(8, 8))

pyplot.scatter(map(lambda x: x[0], circles[0]), map(lambda x: x[1], circles[0]), c = circles[1], cmap = colors)
```

But when I use Python3, I can't do it. I tried to change color but couldn't.

I receive many errors:

```
ValueError: length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1]" 
length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError: Color array must be two-dimensional
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of `matplotlib` are you using with Py2 and Py3?

Comment: Well, if it makes you feel any better, I'm getting the same results with matplotlib 1.5.1 and Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.1 on Linux. Strange...

Comment: 1) Anaconda + Python 2.7.1 +  Matplotlib 1.5.1 - everything is fine
2) Anaconda + Python 3.5.1 +  Matplotlib 1.5.1 - all bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`map` does not return a list in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists). You can either pass the `map` to `list` or use a list comprehension, which is actually shorter than your lambda:

```
pyplot.scatter([x[0] for x in circles[0]], 
               [x[1] for x in circles[0]], c=circles[1], cmap=colors)
```

An even shorter version gets rid of the map completely:

```
 pyplot.scatter(*zip(*circles[0]), c=circles[1], cmap=colors)
```

Comment: I completely forgot about the `map`-list thing in Py3. Something in the back of my mind was bugging me about `map` last night, but I couldn't put my finger on it. Good answer.